# QGIS Rasterize tool returning just a flat black box

Tags: qgis, raster, rasterization

I got the rasterization to run but it is just giving me a flat black box on top of my point vector data. What does the raster suppose to look like? There is no variation or readability to my data. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You have defined a target resolution of 1 by 1 degrees and target extent that spans an area that is smaller than 1 by 1 degree. Therefore one pixel is enough to cover your whole area of interest.

Comment: i tried changing the area and it gives me this error:   GDAL command output:
ERROR 1: Attempt to create 0x0 dataset is illegal,sizes must be larger than zero. 
ERROR 1: Cannot create C:/Users/Shane Adair/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_oeMmKp/20df027bfd024874ae20870e2cb5fa9a/OUTPUT.tif
Process returned error code 1

Comment: Pay attention to resolution (-tr). 1 by 1 degreees is roughly 120 km by 120 km. And please write the commands that you have used / QGIS has created as text. It it not a pleasure to search and interpret them from a screen capture.